# Gradle Build does not include Android Annotations Class

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

I am using Android Annotations for my Android project. I receive during startup of my App at my device the following exception

```
   12-25 15:23:21.325: E/AndroidRuntime(24714): java.lang.RuntimeException:      
    Unable to instantiate activity 
    ComponentInfo{de.myproject.android/de.myproject.android.activity.MainActivity_}:    
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.myproject.android.activity.MainActivity_" 
    on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.myproject.android-56.apk"],
    nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/de.myproject.android-56, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

It seems to be that the generated Android Annotations Classes (MainActivity_) are not included in the apk file.

I am using the following Gradle build file

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal();
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
     }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        multiDexEnabled true      
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    testOptions.unitTests.all {
        testLogging {
            events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.1'

    compile group: 'org.androidannotations', name: 'androidannotations', version: '4.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.androidannotations', name: 'androidannotations-api', version: '4.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'

    compile ('de.myproejct:myApi:v1-1.22.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    }

    compile ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0')  {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    }

    compile 'net.steamcrafted:load-toast:1.0.10'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

The error occured for the first time when I added the following dependency

```
 compile 'net.steamcrafted:load-toast:1.0.10'
```

to my build file. When I remove this dependency my app works perfect on my device.

So what is wrong with my build file or with Android Annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the AndroidAnnotations depency in annotationProcessor scope.

Comment: can you please give some more details? Thanks